# Polar coordinates, integration of arctan

Tags: integration, polar-coordinates

[image]I need to calculate the double integral of $f(x,y)=12\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$ over a domain bounded by several lines.

I've graphed the lines, and they create a region that is a rectangle within a wedge between two circles in region 1.  Ive also found the upper and lower limits of $r_2 = 3$ $r_1 = 1$ and $\theta_2= \frac{\pi}{3}$ and $\theta_1 = \frac{\pi}{6}$.  In now stuck on how to get $12\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$ into the $\cos$ and $\sin$ plugins.  I know that you can have $12\tan^{-1}\frac{r\sin\theta}{r\cos\theta}$ is then $12arctan(\tan \theta) r \frac{dr}{d\theta}$..but im stuck on the next step.
Cheers

Comment: If $\theta\in\left(-\frac\pi 2, \frac\pi 2\right)$, then $\operatorname{arctan}(\tan\theta)=\theta$.

Comment: Hi, not sure what you mean here.

Comment: The functions $\operatorname{arctan}\theta$ and $\tan\theta$ are inverses of each other, so provided you have things in the right domain (which you do, as determined by your bounds) they just undo each other when you plug one into the other.

Comment: Therefore, I would have (for the first integral): theta(pi/3) and theta(pi/6) which are the bounds and 12theta (r^2/2)...

Comment: Right, and you'd evaluate that from $r=1$ to $r=3$

Comment: Then the same bounds (theta*3)/(2)....  d(theta)    does that makes sense.

Comment: I'm not seeing where you get $\frac3 2$

Comment: Im getting confused, i think, Im not sure how to write this out.

Comment: I will write it out and post a photo.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to evaluate $$\int_{\theta=\pi/3}^{\pi/6}\int_{r=1}^3 12\theta r\,dr\,d\theta$$ and as you said you first get $$\int_{\theta=\pi/3}^{\pi/6}12\theta\left.\frac{r^2}{2}\right\vert_{r=1}^3\,d\theta=\int_{\theta=\pi/3}^{\pi/6}6\theta(9-1)\,d\theta.$$ Then simplify and integrate just like you did with respect to $r$.

Comment: Just posted a photo of my working

Comment: Your work looks good.

Comment: I think Ive found a mistake...Ive not integrated twice.

Comment: You integrated w.r.t $r$ in going from $\iint12\theta r$ to $\int12\theta\frac{r^2}{2}$ and then w.r.t $\theta$ in going from that to $2\pi^2$

Comment: Many thanks for all you assistance  - themathandlanguagetutor

Comment: You're quite welcome